# Using Redux in React JS Application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know that there is so many answers in this question.

Anyone explain to me how Redux help your React JS Application more flexible when you are creating a Front End Web Apps.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: As you said there are many, many answers, articles about that. For starter, just go to Redux documentations: https://redux.js.org/faq/general

Comment: @devserkan you're right I know that there so many articles on the internet. But I want the opinions of other developers about Redux and how relevance it is in React JS Application.

Comment: https://medium.com/search?q=redux The firs result is coming from creator of Redux itself.

Answer (score 1):

[From Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react):

> From the very beginning, we need to stress that Redux has no relation
>   to React. You can write Redux apps with React, Angular, Ember, jQuery,
>   or vanilla JavaScript.
>
> That said, Redux works especially well with libraries like React and
>   Deku because they let you describe UI as a function of state, and
>   Redux emits state updates in response to actions.

It's a state management library with a huge ecosystem which lets you more easily set the state for your components across whole application, manage side-effects and many more.

I recommend redux author [course](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) about redux. At later part of the course, he explains how to use it with React.

Answer (score 0):

- Redux is used to manage the state of the component and it supports single state management system, where as flux is a multiple state management system.
- Redux uses dispatchers to dispatch the payload(data) via reducers.